# Enum дного пакета в Enum другого пакета. Java

Tags: java, enum

Есть класс enum A в пакете A1 и есть класс enum A в пакете B2, **A1**.A отличается от **B2**.A только наличием аннотаций XmlEnum и XmlType (название классов одинаковые). Для поддержания совместимости необходимо сделать так, что бы класс объект класса A1.A становился объектом класса B2.A, как это можно сделать?
Просто использовать один класс нельзя, нужно преобразовывать одно в другое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого надо сделать так, что бы оба enum имплементировали один общий для них интерфейс к которому они и будут потом приводиться.